# vim - replace mode to replace new lines too

Tags: vim, newline, mode

In VIM's replace mode, as you type, you don't add any new content, you just replace what is already there.  Only problem is that you *can* add new content when you press enter.  I'd like to know if there is a way so that pressing enter (or `^M`) will be interpreted as `down arrow` when you're in replace mode?

If you must know, I'm working in a file that has segments that are given a fixed number of lines.  I can't add new lines because it will offset subsequent segments.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your requirements this can be achieved in the [virtual replace mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#Virtual-Replace-mode). You can enter it via `gR`.

> Typing a <NL> still doesn't cause characters later in the file to appear to
>   move.  The rest of the current line will be replaced by the <NL> (that is,
>   they are deleted), and **replacing continues on the next line**.  A new line is
>   NOT inserted unless you go past the end of the file.

Please note that vim has to be compiled with `+vreplace`.

Comment: Excellent!  This is exactly what I wanted!